# delete duplicate observations and other specified rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
id     operation     age     shoesize
1        .            24        12
2        .            23        10
1        .            24        11   
3        R -          24         9
4        .            25       -9.5
```

I want to delete the duplicate rows, the rows with 'R -', and the rows with shoesize<0.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I need to i need to save this table too

Comment: What should be your Output with respect the input you have provide

Comment: What is your criteria for duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `id` can't be duplicated, you can do the following:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  id,
            operation,
            age,
            shoesize,
            N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY operation, age, shoesize)
    FROM YourTable
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE N > 1
OR operation = 'R -'
OR shoesize < 0
```

If `id` needs to be taken into account for duplicates, then:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  id,
            operation,
            age,
            shoesize,
            N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY id, operation, age, shoesize)
    FROM YourTable
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE N > 1
OR operation = 'R -'
OR shoesize < 0
```

If you need to delete only the duplicate rows, and want to leave one of those rows, then you need to do:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  id,
            operation,
            age,
            shoesize,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, operation, age, shoesize ORDER BY id)
    FROM YourTable
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
OR operation = 'R -'
OR shoesize < 0
```

Comment: @user2448666 Then you can use the second part of my answer :-)

Comment: haha, didnt read your response thoroughly the first time. Thanks again

Comment: how can i make this last code a new table so I dont have to rebuild my table if it isnt exactly what i want

Comment: @user2448666 hm?, I don't really get what you are asking. But if you don't want to run this code against your real table, you can copy your table to another one, or a temp table and run this query against that table

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table_name
where operation ='R -'
or cast(shoesize as int)< 0
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ba6d/1)**

**`Edit`**

```
delete t1
from Table1 t1
inner join (select ROW_NUMBER()over 
(partition by id, operation, age, shoesize order by id, operation, age, shoesize) 
AS [row_id],* from Table1)t2
on t1.operation=t2.operation and t1.[age]=t2.[age] and t1.shoesize=t2.shoesize
where t2.row_id>1
or t1.[operation] ='R -'
or cast(t1.shoesize as int)< 0
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ba6d/3)**

Comment: that gets the duplicates too?

Comment: What you criteria for duplicate?'

Comment: all matching columns. Guess I failed to insert that into my sample